# Daily Job on a specific time for Android 8.0+

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler, android-8.1-oreo, android-workmanager

I’ve been trying to figure out how to use any of background task APIs in order to create a Work Request that fires every day on a specific time of the day on devices running Android 8.0+.
The time must be set by the user locally on the device (meaning no GCM).

Is that even possible anymore? Legacy devices with `AlarmManager` works wonders, but as far as I am aware all pending intents are cleared when the app gets Force Stopped so it’s a no go now.

`WorkManager`'s `PeriodicWorkRequest` doesn't allow you to set the time to start the Work. I looked into creating a delayed `OneTimeWorkRequest` and schedule the next one after it runs, but nothing ensures that the work will run on the time I want.

Evernote's `Android-Job` library has issues with the `DailyJob` too (https://github.com/evernote/android-job/issues/318).

Any suggestions/ideas more than welcome.

Comment: if you want your job to run on a specific time in android 8, use alarmManager with setInexact.

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO I've tried that, but when you 'Force Stop' the application, the pending intent is gone and the app won't wake up.

Comment: When user is setting it locally you can schedule it with FCM right? Only in that case you will get the alarms on time if you are targeting >=8. As WorkManager doesn't set the alarms on that particular time but near to it.

Comment: There is only no server involved. Only code that runs on the device. FCM is not an option.

Comment: check this project it does the same. https://github.com/cyph3rcod3r/Alliance without FCM and targets android 8

Comment: If your task has no specific requirements like a long running job, doesn't work manger ensures it runs at the required time ?

Comment: @UmarHussain I've only found that you can set a initial delay on the OneTimeWorkRequest, but nothing more than that. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `OneTimeWorkRequest` which schedules a copy of itself before it returns a `Result`.

```
class TestWorker: Worker() {
   fun doWork(): Result {
     val nextWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<TestWorker>()
     nextWorkRequest.withInitialDelay(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
     WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(nextWorkRequest)
     return Result.SUCCESS;
   }
}
```

Start off the first work request with a:

```
 val firstWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<TestWorker>()
 firstWorkRequest.withInitialDelay(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
 WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(firstWorkRequest)
```

Thus you get something which looks like a `PeriodicWorkRequest` with the timing you need.

Answer (score 1):

New PeriodicWorkRequests now support initial delays. So you take the required time from the user, calculate difference between userTime and Now and just set the delay.
Unlike AlarmManeger it is very reliable. 
The only problem is Android fires Worker when it finds the best moment for it (no other work to do), so it may be started with a little delay (usually not more than a few minutes).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using chained tasks in WorkManager. First Schedule *OneTimeWorkRequest*, then chain it with *PeriodicWorkRequest*. Like:

```
WorkManager.getInstance()
.beginWith(workA)
.then(workB)
```

where **workA** is *OneTimeWorkRequest* and **workB** is *PeriodicWorkRequest*

Comment: I am aware of the API. How would you use that to set a specific time to it?